# How to stop a slider animation inside Slider_ValueChanged?

Tags: c#

I am trying to animate a slider. The user should during the animation be able to click/drag on this slider which should stop the animation. However, when I stop the animation the whole application will sometimes freeze so I must be doing something wrong. This never happens when I stop the animation with a button press. So, is it possible to stop the animation inside `Slider_ValueChanged`?
This is the example code I have for testing:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="InteractionSliderAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:10" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractiveSlider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
        </Storyboard>        
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Start" Click="Button_Start"></Button>        
        <Slider Name="InteractiveSlider" IsThumbToolTipEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="500" Maximum="1" StepFrequency="0.001" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
    </Grid>

    private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        counter++; //Only used to know when to stop.
        if(counter == 100)
        {              
            InteractionSliderAnimation.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        counter = 0;
        InteractionSliderAnimation.Begin();
    }
```

To clarify, I am not asking about how to distinguish between the animation causing the call to Slider_ValueChanged and the user causing it. I am asking about why my application is sometimes freezing when stopping the animation inside `Slider_ValueChanged`. Is there a solution to this?